# If Big O is additive and two functions with O(A) and O(B) together would be O(A + B), then why would the same not hold true for two loops?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

The function `myAlgo` has a complexity of `O(A + B)`:

```
function myAlgo() {
  doA(); // O(A);
  doB(); // O(B);
}
```

And `myAlgo2` has a complexity of O(N):

```
function myAlgo2(N) {
  for i in N

  for j in N
}
```

Why does `myAlgo2` not have a complexity of O(N + N)?

For clarity: Stop taking the code too literally. It is pseudo-code (this should be obvious). I commented the complexity of the functions for this reason.

Comment: It is not additive.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum clarifies it deeper.

Comment: O(N + N) = O(2N) = O(N).

Comment: It *is* additive. The Wikipedia link does not claim otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Saying Big-O is additive misses the point of Big-O which is to simplify runtime performance to an asymptotic equation.

Two linear searches (e.g. your loops) may be each O(N) for a total of O(2N), but that's still O(N).

Answer (score 0):

You do not know the complexity of `doA()` and `doB()` functions, which means you have to take into account both of them. Imagine one of them is `O(n^2)` and the other one is `O(n^3)`, then `myAlgo()` would be `O(n^2+n^3)=O(n^3)`, as you take max of both functions.

If you look at `myAlgo2()` function, you have 2 linear loops `O(n)`, which means that `myAlgo2()` is `O(2n)=O(n)`.

To be more precise, you should take a look at the definition of summing big O functions, which will let you apply it to every case you encounter:

```
f1 = O(g1) and f2 = O(g2) => f1 + f2 = O(max(g1, g2))
```

Comment: This is not exactly true. Neither of the functions myAlgo, doA nor doB take input and therefore are all O(1). The second paragraph is correct.

Comment: I do not agree with it, why would a function with no arguments but a loop would be O(1)? You can calculate all simple instructions as O(1), but if you loop through them, the time complexity will be O(n), O(m) or O(x) - there is no difference in the name of the argument, but you can clearly say that it **does not take** constant time.

Comment: Because the big O notation describes scaling with regard to input.

Comment: Can you provide any papers?

Comment: Second paragraph, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation "In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms according to how their run time or space requirements grow as the input size grows."

Comment: @Flutterish Of course you're right that the complexity is O(1) if the function is independent of the inputs, even if it contains nested loops or whatever. But *input* doesn't necessarily mean *function argument*. It totally depends on what you decide on.

Comment: I was wondering about that as well, as it is possible to have global variables and pass nothing to functions, but have higher complexity than O(1) when we work with these.

Comment: Used properties of `this`, `self` or globals are considered input, but given the question I assumed that was not the case, as there is no class declaration nor any values from outter scope. If there is a use of these, then of course you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Your myAlgo2 has complexity of O(N+N).

Wich you can write as O(2N).

Wich you can write as 2O(N) and since 2 is constant it can be ignored so Complexity of myAlgo2 is  O(N).

Since myAlgo has complexity O(A+B) you can't do the same becuase A might not be B.

Note: even if complexity does not change in real case scenario having O(2N) or O(N) will still make a (sometimes huge) difference.

Comment: Having O(2N) vs O(N) can never make a difference because the two sets are equal. 2N vs N certainly makes a difference.

Comment: O(2N) = O(N), you drop the constant values

Comment: it does make a difference in real case scenario with huge chunks of data

Comment: @rallolollo No, of course it doesn't, by definition of O(*f*).